# C# ODATA , Expand N Level with sub-entities

Tags: c#, odata

I really need your help to achieve the following :

First let me show you my DB data model :

```
1- mebs_schedule=>mebs_ingesta
2- mebs_ingesta=>mebs_ingestadetails
3- mebs_ingesta=>mebs_videoitem
4- mebs_ingesta=>mebs_channel=>mebs_channeltuning
```

using the URI below i can get this tree for a giving Schedule reference :

```
mebs_schedule=>mebs_ingesta

mebs_ingesta=>mebs_ingestadetails

mebs_ingesta=>mebs_videoitem

mebs_ingesta=> mebs_channel
```

URI = `"mebs_schedule({0})?$expand=mebs_ingesta/mebs_videoitem,mebs_ingesta/mebs_ingestadetails,mebs_ingesta/mebs_channel"`

Now i wanna get also associated mebs_channeltuning collection for each mebs_channel occurence.

i have spend time in google to find out how achive this but nothing.

Some tentatives :

`mebs_schedule(79)?$expand=mebs_ingesta&expand=mebs_videoitem,mebs_ingestadetails,mebs_channel&expand=mebs_channe.mebs_channeltuning`

Last question is there any way to expand all imported Data Model .

Thanks for your help.

Env : VS .NET 2010 / C# 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work just fine:

```
URI = "mebs_schedule({0})?$expand=mebs_ingesta/mebs_videoitem,mebs_ingesta/mebs_ingestadetails,mebs_ingesta/mebs_channel/mebs_channeltuning"
```

I just added "/mebs_channeltuning" at the end. Note that you don't need to explicitely expand the mebs_channel only since it will be expanded due to its child being expanded (after that change).

The tentative solution has many issues. One is that expand needs the $ sign before it (otherwise it's not recognized as a query option). Second is that the server will usually only accept one $expand query option. (and that . is not the separator for the expansions).

There's no way to expand everything. This is intentional as expansions make the data grow potentially exponentially and thus could cause problems both on the server and on the client. The client has to explicitly ask for every expansion.

Comment: Thanks Vitek, i have already test that, and i got the error "An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details."

Comment: And do you have the inner exception?