# How to expand sub levels of childs with AutoMapper and OData?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6, odata, automapper

I'm currently working on a web service project in asp.net. And I try to include child elements in my function that retrieves the data.

It works with the url :

```
http://localhost:8080/myEntity/?$expand=myChildElement
```

But I can't seem to include the child elements of a level below like this :

```
http://localhost:8080/myEntity/?$expand=myChildElement/mySubChildElement
```

Here is my function :

```
public virtual async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetElements(ODataQueryOptions<TEntity> queryOptions)
{
    IQueryable<TPoco> query = context.Set<TPoco>();

    string[] includes = null;
    string includeText = queryOptions.SelectExpand != null ? queryOptions.SelectExpand.RawExpand : null;
    if(! string.IsNullOrEmpty(includeText))
    {
        includes = queryOptions.SelectExpand.RawExpand.Split(',');
        return Ok(await query.ProjectTo<TEntity>(null, includes).ToListAsync());
    }

    return Ok(await query.ProjectTo<TEntity>().ToListAsync());
}
```

And here is an example of my TPoco model (myChildElement can be the entity "Project" and mySubChildElement the child entity "ProjectType") :

```
public class ContractEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public ContractEntity()
    {
        this.Addresses = new HashSet<AddressEntity>();
    }

    override public Guid Id { get; set; }
    override public string DisplayName { get { return No.ToString(); } set { } }
    override public string ClassType { get { return "Contract"; } set { } }
    override public string MarkerColor { get { return Colors.Green.ToString(); } set { } }
    public int? No { get; set; }
    public DateTime? OfficialDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ValidDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SignatureDate { get; set; }
    public Guid? ProjectId { get; set; }
    [...]

    public virtual ICollection<AccountingItemEntity> AccountingItems { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TagEntity> Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual ProjectEntity Project { get; set; }
    [...]
}
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058485/c-sharp-odata-expand-n-level-with-sub-entities?rq=1

Comment: @ShaneRay: I think not. I understand the OData system, but what I want is to incorporate it into my function GetElements.

Comment: I think you may need to replace the `/` with `.` in your function.  This would mean you pass `myChildElement.mySubChildElement` to the `ProjectTo` method.  Also it is possibly case-sensitive so make sure your casing is correct.

Comment: @ShaneRay: With `/` I have the message : _Found a path traversing multiple navigation properties. Please rephrase the query such that each expand path contains only type segments and navigation properties._. And with `.` I have the second message : _Could not find a property named myChildElement.mySubChildElement_

Comment: Can you add TPoco model to the question?

Comment: @ShaneRay : TPoco model added. Here, the request I would like to send is `http://localhost:8080/contracts/?$expand=Project/ProjectType`

Comment: Okay, it looks like you are running into a similar issue I did when I was working with OData and Projections... Basically the projections got in the way and caused things to not work properly.. I ended up ditching OData and writing my own filtering system.  https://github.com/shaneray/ShaneSpace.ProjectedDynamicLinq

Comment: You could just add the include to the initial query via `Include()` but if you have changed any property names these will not map up properly.

Comment: Instead of `http://localhost:8080/myEntity/?$expand=myChildElement/mySubChildElement` you might want to try: `http://localhost:8080/myEntity?$expand=myChildElement($expand=mySubChildElement)`

Comment: @GWigWam: I have tried everything, your proposal too. I think, the solution is to change the code of my function "GetElements".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way I do this, I use the fact that `.ProjectTo` returns an `IQueryable` so I let the OData framework handle querying by not calling `ToListAsync()` myself, but returning the `IQueryable`.

```
// In some class that is ': ODataController'
[EnableQuery] //Attribute makes sure the OData framework handles querying
public IQueryable<TDto> Get(ODataQueryOptions<TDto> options) {
    //The names of the properties requested by the client in the '$expand=' query option
    string[] requestedExpands = Helpers.Expand.GetMembersToExpandNames(options); // I made a helper for this, you can probably just use your code, or see my impementation below.

    var set = Db.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking(); //You might want to remove AsNoTracking if it doesn't work
    var converted = set.ProjectTo<TDto>(MapConfig, null, requestedExpands);
    return converted;
}
```

In this example `TDto` is the type I want to sent to the client `TEntity` is the Entity Framework POCO class.

My `MapConfig` I setup on application startup, here I set expandable properties to 'Explicit expand' mode:

```
MapConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<EFType, DTOType>(MemberList.Destination)
        .ForMember(c => c.ExpandableProperty, options => options.ExplicitExpansion());
});
```

As I said in comments, I request the data by nesting `$expand=` in the URL:

```
api/myEntity?$expand=myChildElement($expan‌​d=mySubChildElement)
```

This works for me, hope you can replicate that success.

**EDIT:** Looked at it again, if you want to expand `myEntity.myChildElement.mySubChildElement` the `string[]` 'requestedExpands' you pass to AutoMapper must contain 1 entry: `myChildElement.mySubChildElement`. And I have a mapping defined for all 3 entities, again with the `ExplicitExpansion` option.

---

Update, as requested by @Tim Pohlmann, my implementation of `GetMembersToExpandNames`:

```
public static class Expand {

    public static string[] GetMembersToExpandNames(ODataQueryOptions options) {
        return GetExpandPropertyPaths(GetExpandItems(options?.SelectExpand?.SelectExpandClause)).ToArray();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetExpandPropertyPaths(IEnumerable<ExpandedNavigationSelectItem> items, string prefix = "") {
        foreach(var item in items) {
            foreach(var res in GetExpandPropertyPaths(item, prefix)) {
                yield return res;
            }
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetExpandPropertyPaths(ExpandedNavigationSelectItem item, string prefix = "") {
        var curPropName = item.NavigationSource.Name;
        var nestedExpand = GetExpandItems(item.SelectAndExpand).ToArray();
        if(nestedExpand.Count() > 0) {
            foreach(var res in GetExpandPropertyPaths(nestedExpand, $"{prefix}{curPropName}.")) {
                yield return res;
            }
        } else {
            yield return $"{prefix}{curPropName}";
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<ExpandedNavigationSelectItem> GetExpandItems(SelectExpandClause sec) {
        if(sec != null) {
            var res = sec?.SelectedItems?.OfType<ExpandedNavigationSelectItem>();
            if(res != null) {
                return res;
            }
        }
        return new ExpandedNavigationSelectItem[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: The implementation of `GetMemebersToExpandNames` would be very helpful.

Comment: @TimPohlmann, Have added my implementation, I've not used this code in a while so I'm not certain it'll work, but this is what I use.